# Checkstyle with Maven plugin has not expected failed checks

Tags: java, maven, coding-style, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have *my_checkstyle.xml* file. I assume it is based on **Sun's checkstyle.**
It is located in separated module that is built together with other common modules for the project. I try to useit for the specific service module and run checkstyle plugins there.

What I have done:

1. Added to pom.xml of checkstyle module, that consists of only pom.xml and my_checkstyle.xml files:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>my_checkstyle.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Then I have added to my common base module this:

```
<build>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
</build>
```

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>../checkstyle-config/my_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

1. Re-built my common project.
2. Reloaded maven and rebuilt my service where I use common dependency module(second step seems to be not required).
   After that I dont have checkstyle plugin added in Maven plugins list.

I tried another way by adding checkstyle module as dependency to my service directly:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle-config</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>../../../common/checkstyle-config/my_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

After just reloading Maven, I have got Checkstyle plugin.
Main problem is - Checkstyle seems not reading my_checkstyle.xml. I have noticed that after commenting all checks in my_checkstyle.xml(and rebuild), it still fails on the same checks.

For example:

`(javadoc) JavadocPackage: Missing package-info.java file.`

`(javadoc) MissingJavadocMethod: Missing a Javadoc comment.`

`(misc) FinalParameters: Parameter event should be final.`

Also, for some reason `checkstyle:checkstyle` does nothing except *Build Success* messages, but `checkstyle:check` runs checks and I see the report.
What did I wrong to run checkstyle correctly?

Comment: I haven't used this plugin by myself, but since Maven plugins follow the [convention over configuration](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html) principle the behavior you describe may indicate that your config is not used at all and the default checks are being run. Is the path to your `my_checkstyle.xml` config correct?

Comment: well I assumed that path could be incorrect, but I can't know... I assume IDEA does correct suggestion with autocompletion. I had to "cd .." few times from service module to the root and go to another package, where is located project with checkstyle. Or should I use some trick? @AlexanderPletnev